# Flutter doctor: Flutter and dart plugins not installed

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

This is problem, I have already installed flutter and dart plugin but its showing I haven't , I freshly installed both android studio and flutter as I just started it

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable`enter code here`, on Microsoft Windows)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[√] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known and recurring issue with Flutter cli and the 'moving target' that is AS4.1 and other IDE file locations. See: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/61246
(and the links it contains).

It can be safely ignored if your plugins in AS4.1 are working fine.

Comment: Why did you remove this as the accepted answer?

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit confused with some answers, as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65554482/  problem occurred but its now working fine, so I thought this was not the correct solution, Thanks for helping bro!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the Flutter and Dart plug-ins to your Android Studio. Simply open the Android Studio program, select File > Settings > Plugins (or Android Studio > Preferences > Plugins on a Mac). Type in The word flutter to bring up the flutter.dev plug-in and click to install it. Installing Flutter will automatically install Dart. Rerun flutter doctor again, and assuming your $PATH is configured correctly, it will show that the plug-ins are detected.

Comment: I have already installed flutter plugin with dart one but it is not detecting it

Comment: What does echo $PATH show? Does “which flutter dart” point to the proper spot?

Comment: thanks for willing to help buddy, but its now working fine as I have ignored them!

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem for the last two months. It happened after the new Flutter update. I tried every solution: whether changing Channel to dev to updating SDKs. I have been ignoring it and everything works perfectly .

Answer (score 0):

Check if Android Studio is added to your `Path` in `environment variables`

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your flutter sample project is running or not ,if it is running finely then it will not create problem. I am saying this because i happend with me also but it didn't affected any projects i have created.

Comment: hey, I tried to run the auto generated code in it, but it gave me error, which I have given in [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65550669/ ,please help if you know the solution

Comment: Not a proper solution but try to reinstall plugin  . These are the problems that occurred with me as well it took me nearly week to operate flutter properly and i also didn't find solution anywhere just tried myself again and again