# I can't run automated generated code of flutter in android studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

```
 Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1533)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.available(AppInputStream.java:60)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.available(BufferedInputStream.java:410)
    at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.available(MeteredStream.java:170)
```

code countinues....

```
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:181)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.close(HttpURLConnection.java:3527)
    
at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:77)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
```

I want to run auto generated code for the first time with android studio, to test that all is correctly set, but I can't, It shows the error in the given picture, I am new to this so please help

Comment: No screenshots of text please.  Paste the text enclosed with ``` on a line by itself both before and after the text.

Comment: this also comes same problem with vscode