# Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch [React-native]

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, error-handling

**Version**

```
react native:0.68.2
react native cli: 2.0.1
node:v18.13.0
jdk:jdk-8.0.342.07-hotspot
```

when I run this cmd to run my project in react native it's give me error

```
npx react-native run-android or react-native run-android
```

it's give me this type error

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
(node:6120) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Jetifier found 936 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip

Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:133)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:267)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:262)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:119)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1400)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1368)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.access$300(SSLSocketImpl.java:73)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:962)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
        at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:134)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3456)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3449)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:106)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:80)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:68)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)
Caused by: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.decryptFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:620)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1116)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1053)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:941)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:491)
        at javax.crypto.CipherSpi.bufferCrypt(CipherSpi.java:779)
        at javax.crypto.CipherSpi.engineDoFinal(CipherSpi.java:730)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2463)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLCipher$T12GcmReadCipherGenerator$GcmReadCipher.decrypt(SSLCipher.java:1606)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decodeInputRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:262)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:190)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:109)
        ... 18 more

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:133)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:267)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:262)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:119)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1400)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1368)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.access$300(SSLSocketImpl.java:73)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:962)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
        at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:134)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3456)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3449)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:106)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:80)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:68)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)
Caused by: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.decryptFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:620)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1116)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1053)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:941)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:491)
        at javax.crypto.CipherSpi.bufferCrypt(CipherSpi.java:779)
        at javax.crypto.CipherSpi.engineDoFinal(CipherSpi.java:730)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2463)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLCipher$T12GcmReadCipherGenerator$GcmReadCipher.decrypt(SSLCipher.java:1606)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decodeInputRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:262)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:190)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:109)
        ... 18 more

    at makeError (C:\Users\dp312\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\LoanApp\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\dp312\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\LoanApp\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\dp312\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\LoanApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\dp312\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\LoanApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

[image: here is error img]

```
android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties
```

in this file I can change like this but it also not work

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip <---here https to http
or
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

**I know where is problem**

- first one I install Android studio it's give me same error when I install Android studio and SDK then
- I find a video which one do react native project without Android studio so I can follow the video and try to run my project but still my project give me error
- I don't know why this error is come
- my network connectivity is stable no issue in a network connectivity then why this error is come and my project is new in my project no have any dependency and any code simple code of hello word in my project
- but still it's give me a error
  any one can give me solution??

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP protocol may be the most commonly used and important protocol on the Internet today, and more and more Java applications require direct access to network resources through the HTTP protocol. Although the basic functionality to access the HTTP protocol is already provided in the JDK's java. net package, for most applications, the JDK library itself does not provide rich and flexible functionality. HttpClient is a sub project under Apache Jakarta Common, designed to provide an efficient, up-to-date, and feature rich client programming toolkit that supports the HTTP protocol. It also supports the latest versions and recommendations of the HTTP protocol.

you can try bypass SSL and HTTPS certificates. like that,

```
private static CloseableHttpClient client = null;
static {
    SSLContext sslcontext = null;
    try {
        sslcontext = createIgnoreVerifySSL();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
            .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.INSTANCE)
            .register("https", new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext))
            .build();
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);
    HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(connManager);
    client = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(connManager).build();
}
public static SSLContext createIgnoreVerifySSL() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSLv3");

    // 实现一个X509TrustManager接口，用于绕过验证，不用修改里面的方法
    X509TrustManager trustManager = new X509TrustManager() {
        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(
                java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] paramArrayOfX509Certificate,
                String paramString) throws CertificateException {
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(
                java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] paramArrayOfX509Certificate,
                String paramString) throws CertificateException {
        }

        @Override
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
    };
    sc.init(null, new TrustManager[]{trustManager}, null);
    return sc;
}
```